# The HTTP HEAD request is returning a 404 Not Found error

Tags: .net-core, wso2, swagger-ui, wso2-api-manager, http-head

I am using WSO2 API Manager to publish my WebApi Gateway, which is connected to my REST services. However, when I try to create an Import Open API, the endpoint fails to verify due to an HTTP HEAD request that returns a 404 Not Found error. My Gateway is built using .NET Core 3.1 and the Swagger version is 2.0. I am unsure whether the issue is with WSO2, Swagger, or .NET Core 3.1. Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Maybe it only allows the GET http method and you need to add HEAD as well.

Comment: It doesn't call any function, it just checks the endpoint.

Comment: Can you share which WSO2 APIM Version you are using?